# Function which changes strings of filenames based on a list

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have multiple folders with csv files in them, and I am creating Cartesian lists and running some statistics on all file combinations.

So far I am executing this like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats
import glob
import itertools
#
#
path =r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\NDVI' # use your path
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
result = list(itertools.product(allfiles,allfiles))
#
dataframe=[]
for files in result:
     x=(pd.read_csv(files[0], names = ['Percent', 'Value']))
     z=x.Percent
     y=(pd.read_csv(files[1], names = ['Percent', 'Value']))
     d=y.Percent
     stats2=sp.stats.ks_2samp(z,d)
     g=files, stats2
     df=pd.DataFrame(data=list(sum(g, ())), index=['File1', 'File2', 'D', 'p_value']).transpose()
     dataframe.append(df)
df=pd.concat(dataframe)
print df
```

but my problem is I have multiple folders I need to navigate to within a pathway.  So `r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\NDVI'` is just one of many folders I need to execute this code on.  Is there a way to create a function and change the string of the pathway to do this?  So if the next folder location is `r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\NDII'` and I have a list with the names `NDVI` and `NDII` I want to automate it to run the same code on the next folder by simply changing the string (only the portion after `r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\`) within the pathway based on the items in the list.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function:

```
def get_df(path):
    allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    result = list(itertools.product(allfiles,allfiles))
    #
    dataframe=[]
    for files in result:
        x=(pd.read_csv(files[0], names = ['Percent', 'Value']))
        z=x.Percent
        y=(pd.read_csv(files[1], names = ['Percent', 'Value']))
        d=y.Percent
        stats2=sp.stats.ks_2samp(z,d)
        g=files, stats2
        df=pd.DataFrame(data=list(sum(g, ())), index=['File1', 'File2', 'D', 'p_value']).transpose()
        dataframe.append(df)
    return pd.concat(dataframe)
```

and use it for all your paths:

```
import os

paths = [os.path.join(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats', name)
         for name in ['NDVI', 'NDII']]
dfs = [get_df(path) for path in paths]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better idea: just wrap the original in a loop.

```
for folder in ('NDVI', 'NDII'):
    path =r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\' + folder
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in the following kind of loop:

```
import os

root_path = r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats'
folders = ['NDVI', 'NDII']

for folder in folders:
    path = os.path.join(root_path, folder, '*.csv')
    print path
    allfiles = glob.glob(path)
```

[`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) correctly joins any number of parts together to form a valid path suitable for your operating system. This would display the following output:

```
F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\NDVI\*.csv
F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\NDII\*.csv
```